# Replace a value in yaml file with multi line string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have been trying to replace/add value of a field in yaml with an env variable that has multi line string, using below syntax

```
replacewith=" |-
  multi
  line
  string"
sed -i -e "s/^\(\s*key-in-yaml\s*:\s*\).*/\1 $replacewith/"  somefile.yaml
```

We can assume that `key-in-yaml` doesn't have any value by default. Above comand results in

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command
```

I also want the indentation to be maintained.

If this is the content of yaml file

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterServiceVersion
metadata:
  annotations:
    alm-examples:
    capabilities: Basic Install
```

after that `sed` command i was expecting

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterServiceVersion
metadata:
  annotations:
    alm-examples: |-
      multi
      line
      string
    capabilities: Basic Install
```

Comment: Good that you have posted your efforts in your question. Could you please samples of input and expected output too in your question to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added the samples.

Comment: Thanks for editing it, you want to insert it after `annotations:`?'

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 for the key `annotations.alm-examples`

Comment: Suggest using a YAML parser like `yq`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following, in case you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk -v str="$replacewith" '
1;
/annotations:/{ found=1 }
found && /alm-examples: \|-/{
  print str
  found=""
}
' Input_file
```

Once you are happy with above results(which will be shown on terminal) and in case you want to save them into Input_file itself then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to above command.

Answer (score 2):

`sed -E '/alm-examples/s/(.*)$/printf "\1 $replacewith"/e' somefile.yaml`

This uses `s///e` to shell out to `printf` which will handle the multiline string better than attempts to inline it with sed commands.  It is `printf` expanding the string, not `sed`, because the sed command is in single quotes.

This also works, with `&` replacing the `\1`, because the line break doesn't get passed to printf either way:

`sed -E '/alm-examples/s/.*/printf "& $replacewith"/e' somefile.yaml`

Or, to depend on `annotations:` in the prior line:

`sed -E '/annotations:/{N;/alm-examples/s/.*/printf "& $replacewith"/e}' somefile.yaml`

Comment: it looks like the env variable is not being substituted in the sed command. if I replace `$replacewith` with `somevalue` it works other wise not.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use `yq` and it has been working great even for complex fields in yaml for example `a.b.c[0].d=env-var-multiline`.